# como eu posso fazer para o meu carrossel mudar de imagem sem javascript

Tags: html, css

Ola,

Eu criei um carrossel com 3 imagens e queria fazer com que elas fossem mudando automaticamente sem precisar de correr um codigo javascript.

Ja estive a pesquisar mas todos me recomendam usar javascript e as outras formas de fazer mudar a imagens não estão a funcionar.

Recorrendo ao codigo abaixo eu gostava de saber como posso fazer as imagens trocarem de 5 em 5 segundos apenas com html e css.

```js
window.location = "#img1";
```

```css
.carrossel {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.carrossel img {
    width: 1280px;
    height: auto;
}

.carrossel .img {
    display: none;
}

.carrossel .img:target {
    display: block;
}

.carrossel .b1 {
    position: relative;
}

.carrossel .b2 {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="carrossel">
            <div class="img1 img" id="img1">
                <img src="../img/img_1_car.png" alt="img1">
                <button class="b1"><a href="#img3">Voltar</a></button>
                <button class="b2"><a href="#img2">Avançar</a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="img2 img" id="img2">
                <img src="../img/img_2_car.jpg" alt="img2">
                <button class="b1"><a href="#img1">Voltar</a></button>
                <button class="b2"><a href="#img3">Avançar</a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="img3 img" id="img3">
                <img src="../img/img_3_car.jpg" alt="img3">
                <button class="b1"><a href="#img2">Voltar</a></button>
                <button class="b2"><a href="#img1">Avançar</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: sem javascript? tem certeza?

Comment: @GabrielOliveira eu não percebo muito de javascript é mais por isso... mas se me conseguir explicar bem pode ser mas preferia sem javascript

Comment: Olha, só com css e html não vai rolar, assim vc faria sua pagina completamente estática, se vc puder, da uma estudada sobre [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/carousel/), já tem tudo pronto

Comment: @GabrielOliveira eu ate gostaria de usar bootstrap mas uma das regras para o meu trabalho é não poder usar isso...

Comment: Oque lida com comportamentos é justamente o javascript, como o Gabriel Oliveira disse, sem isso sua página será estática. Mas se você der uma procurada tem muito material sobre javascript que pode ajudar a começar.

Comment: Meus 2cents aqui. Uma **"Googleada"** rapida e vc encontrará pérolas como esta: https://codepen.io/koheishingai/pen/uKvJF